# undefined is not a function (evaluating 'RNViewShot.captureRef(view,options)')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to save a view in android by react native.In Expo while taking viewshot, the React native viewshot throws the below error in android. This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { View ,Image,Button} from 'react-native';
import ViewShot from "react-native-view-shot"
import { captureRef } from "react-native-view-shot";
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
super(props)
this.capture = this.capture.bind(this)
}
capture(){
 this.refs.viewShot.capture().then(uri => {
  console.log("do something with ", uri);
},(error)=>{console.log("error",error)})
}
render() {
return (
  <View  style={styles.container}>
  <ViewShot ref="viewShot" >
    <Image  source={require("./batman.jpg")}>
    </Image>
  </ViewShot>
  <Button
  title="save"
  onPress={this.capture}
  >
  </Button>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @Think-Twice I added my code.